# Prove convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^3\left(\frac{\pi n}{n+5}\right)}{\sqrt{n^2+n}-n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, absolute-convergence

> I need to prove convergence of the series.
>   $$
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n,\ \ 
> a_n=\frac{\sin^3\left(\frac{\pi n}{n+5}\right)}{\sqrt{n^2+n}-n}
> $$

Well, at first I noticed that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\ a_n>0$:
$$
\left.
\begin{aligned}
&0<\frac{\pi n}{n+5}<\pi\Rightarrow\sin^3\left(\frac{\pi n}{n+5}\right)>0\\
&\sqrt{n^2+n}>n\Rightarrow\sqrt{n^2+n}-n>0
\end{aligned}
\right\}\Rightarrow a_n>0
$$
So, then I tried to apply comparison test to this series. However, it was not helpful since no matter how I bounded $\sin^3\left(\frac{\pi n}{n+5}\right)$, I could not find $b_n\geqslant a_n:\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ is convergent.

Thus, I would be glad if someone could give me some clue to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\sin (\frac {\pi n} {n+5})=\sin (\pi -\frac {\pi n} {n+5})=\sin (\frac {5\pi } {n+5})$ and $|\sin (\frac {5\pi } {n+5})| \leq \frac {5\pi } {n+5}$. Now compare the sreies with $\sum \frac 1 {n^{3}}$.

Comment: Well, it was rather easy. How haven't I noticed it? Thank you for your help!

Comment: It seems that $\sum \frac 1 {n^{4}}$ doesn't work. You need to better evaluate the full expression.

Comment: The denominator behaves like a constant. So nothing more is needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. @user

Comment: @KaboMurphy You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\sin^3\left(\frac{\pi n}{n+5}\right)=\sin^3\left(\frac{\pi n+\pi 5-\pi 5}{n+5}\right)=\sin^3\left(\pi-\frac{\pi 5}{n+5}\right)=$$

$$=\sin^3\left(\frac{\pi 5}{n+5}\right) \sim \left(\frac{\pi 5}{n+5}\right)^3$$

and

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}-n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}-n}\frac{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n}=\frac{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n}{n}\sim 2$$

therefore $a_n \sim \frac1{n^3}$ and the given series converges by comparison test.

Comment: Is that last denominator really n^2?

Comment: @imranfat Ops...thanks I fix that.